# Google Cloud Endpoints - Return another resource in resource getter

Tags: java, api, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

So a typical Cloud Endpoints API method might look like this.

```
@ApiMethod(path = "myresources/{id}")
public MyResource get(@Named("id") int id) { … }
```

But what if a getter in the MyResouce class returned MySecondResource?

Technically the supported types are listed here.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types

But what are the work a rounds. Obviously one resource should be able to have a getter that returns another.

Comment: This seems to be an issue of lazy loading if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POJO getter getMySecondResource() is supported in endpoints. You can lazily load the value inside the getter.

The list in the link you mentioned, is for the method parameters.

Comment: I tried that.The problem seemed to have something to do with using using the local API client. I seemed to work int he JS client, but not with the local API utility. Whatever.